# What is the maximum amount of Activities you can define in a Manifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am building an application and it is going to have a lot of activities defined. There will be hundreds of different screens for specific options and such. I know it's probably not a good idea to define a ton of Activities in the manifest

Is there a maximum amount of Activities you can define in the Manifest?

Will a lot of Activities defined in the manifest affect anything like startup time or the time it takes to load up a new Activity?

Comment: As @Szymon pointed out, you can have n number of activities. Just that you will take a performance hit.

Comment: just a small suggestion if it can help you....you can have fragments for each screen, you can logically group fragments and can have single activity for each group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it good for creating hundreds activity for user experience perspective? Not. It has performance affects as @Szymon said. Can you determine the identical activity from those activities. If can then you can create only one activity and perform similar operation based on dynamic condition.

Comment: This is probably the best answer you can get. The issue is not really the number of Activities, or even the performance aspect, but this is going to be a nightmare to update/debug, and the UX may feel overwhelming...

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the number of Activities defined in the manifest and the number of Activities active at any time (the number on the Activity stack).    Having hundreds of Activities in the manifest is not necessarily so bad.  Having ten or twenty of them on the stack is likely produce undesirable behaviors.

Consider an alternate design of a single activity that may be instantiated a few times, and dynamically attaches one of hundreds of Fragments.